# Enable Button by writing something into a textbox issue

Tags: c#, button, textbox

I want to enable a button by writing something into multiple textboxes. I'm using the following code for every single TextBox, but the button is not enabling. Even if I try with only 1 TextBox. Button Enabled is set to false. This is the code:

```
private void UsernameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int notEmptyTextBoxCount = 0;
    int textBoxCount = 0;
    foreach (var item in Controls)
    {
        if (item is TextBox txtb)
        {
            textBoxCount++;
            if (txtb.Text != String.Empty)
                 notEmptyTextBoxCount++;
        }
    }
    if (textBoxCount == notEmptyTextBoxCount)
        submitButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

I'm still new to programming. Do you have any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, are you sure that this method is called after you write something down? If you are using WindowsForms, you have to go to your designer, click on the textbox for which you want to apply this method, go to right, click on the lighting symbol and choose your method for TextChanged.

Comment: Yeah but it's still not working idk

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the event name in the property of each text box is the same as the event name in the code. And try to write the shared code in the form of a method and call that shared method when calling the change event of each text box, as below:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   enableSubmitButton();
}
 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    enableSubmitButton();
 } 
 private void enableSubmitButton()
 {
    int notEmptyTextBoxCount = 0;
    int textBoxCount = 0;
    foreach (var item in Controls)
    {
       if (item is TextBox txtb)
       {
          textBoxCount++;
          if (txtb.Text != String.Empty)
             notEmptyTextBoxCount++;
           }
         }
        if (textBoxCount == notEmptyTextBoxCount)
          button1.Enabled = true;
     }
```